# Gitlab fatal repository not found on Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio, gitlab

I am trying to commit my code to gitlab. I am able to commit via cmd but unable to commit from Android Studio. I am getting this error "repository not found. fatal: repository not found". PFA image of the same.

> fatal: repository '....' not found